# Retrieve data from attribute

Tags: python

I'm developing a program that generate signals and after process them. I've created 2 classes: the first to define parameters and the second to get a value to the parameters.
This is Parameters class:

```
class Signals_Parameters:
    
    def __init__(self, name, minValue, maxValue):
        self.name = name
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue
```

This is the class to get the parameters value:

```
from Signal_Param import Signals_Parameters

class SignalDefinition:
   
    def signaldefinition(self):
        self.signal = []
        self.signal.append(Signals_Parameters("S1", 0, 100))
        print(self.signal)
SignalDefinition().signaldefinition()
```

How can I use the data contained in "signals" in a SeriesGenerator class?

PS:In the following class I used "print" only to check if was correct

SeriesGenerator class:

```
from Signal_Definition import SignalDefinition

class SeriesGenerator:
    
    def retrieve_signal_info(self):
        signals = SignalDefinition()
        signal_info = signals.signaldefinition
        print(signal_info)
        
SeriesGenerator().retrieve_signal_info()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'SeriesGenerator'? What would you like to do with this generator?

Comment: I want to use data contained in 'signal' ("S1", 0, 100) to create a tuple with (x,y) and create a chart using the Plotly lib

Comment: What exactly would you like to plot? The class, as it is right now, only contains the numbers 0 and 100.

Comment: I'll use random() to generate values between 0 and 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean below.  Just define an `__init__` and pass
instance of `SignalDefinition` to it

```
class Signals_Parameters:
    
    def __init__(self, name, minValue, maxValue):
        self.name = name
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue
        
class SignalDefinition:
   
    def signaldefinition(self):
        self.signal = []
        self.signal.append(Signals_Parameters("S1", 0, 100))
        print(self.signal)
        
class SeriesGenerator:
    def __init__(self, sigdef):
        self.sigdef = sigdef
    
    def retrieve_signal_info(self):
        signals = SignalDefinition()
        signal_info = signals.signaldefinition
        print(signal_info)
        
sd = SignalDefinition()
sd.signaldefinition()
SeriesGenerator(sd).retrieve_signal_info()
```